# Постоянный realtime замер скорости интернета

Tags: python, скорость

Суть в том, есть ли такое приложение на Android или же можно просто код на Python, который регулярно замеряет скорость интернета, мол я иду по территории и просматриваю в реальном времени просадки интернета в той или иной части территории?

Comment: Да миллион таких приложений. Выбирайте: https://play.google.com/store/apps/collection/cluster?clp=ggElCiPQutCw0YfQtdGB0YLQstC-INC40L3RgtC10YDQvdC10YLQsA%3D%3D:S:ANO1ljJpiAQ&gsr=CiiCASUKI9C60LDRh9C10YHRgtCy0L4g0LjQvdGC0LXRgNC90LXRgtCw:S:ANO1ljJw8Co

Comment: Я использую iperf3 (в Termux-окружении)

Answer (score 1):

Вот простенький код, который замеряет скорость 1000 раз. На один замер уходит около 10 секунд. Не судите строго, я новичок)
для работы нужно установить `pip install speedtest-cli`

```
import speedtest



def speed():

 for i in range (1000):
   test = speedtest.Speedtest()
   download = test.download()
   upload = test.upload()
   print(f"Speed: {(download/1024)/1024} Mb/s \n Upload Speed : {(upload/1024)/1024} Mb/s")
   

speed()
```

Comment: какой модуль нужно установить?

Comment: pip install speedtest-cli